# Java method overloading with "default" argument values

Tags: java, overloading

First of all, I know that officially, the answer to this question is that it simply cannot be done in a native Java environment. So I'm not asking if this is something that Java can do natively. I'm simply asking if it can be done in Java AT ALL - perhaps by some other means that I am not aware of.

I've been experimenting with a library that I want to have where a developer can interact with an object where that object can be identified by not making a reference to it, where I then simply refer to it in the library by a default name, OR, the developer can assign names to the object in which case, each new name given will create a new instance of the object in the library.

But in terms of providing the public methods that are relevant to what the library does, I've been having to create TWO of every method and this has significantly increased the size of the library where so much of it has to be duplicated because of the way Java does method overloading. And yes, I do consolidate repeating code everywhere I can but it doesn't change the fact that I have to create two methods for each offered function.

Ideally, this

```
public static void getThis(float value, String objectName) {
   //related code for objectName
}

public static void getThis(float value) {
  //related code for the defaultObjectName
}
```

Becomes this if I could assign a default value for objectName

```
public static void getThis(float value, String objectName = defaultObjectName) {
  //related code handles objectName
}
```

So my question is, can this be done by ANY means at all - third-party options maybe?

Also, does anyone know why Java does not offer this ability?

edit: I deleted a portion of this last question after reading the first comment.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. This question is either asking for third-party tools or ranting about why the language doesn't work the way you want it to - either way, it's off topic for Stack Overflow. Phrases like "Is it some kind of law violation" don't help the case for a good-faith question, either.

Comment: That said: Java is an *especially poor* example of an "object-oriented" language, by most typical standards. Most notably, many things are *not objects* in Java that would be in other languages, such as Python. But also, OOP has *nothing to do with* the question; there's no reason a language with no concept of an "object" would be prevented from having a concept of a "default argument", and also no reason why "object-orientation" should require default arguments for functions or methods.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Im certainly not ranting nor am I complaining ... that is by no means the intent of my question. I assume that Java does not offer this ability for a good reason, though I don't know what that is... I meant no discord by this post what so ever.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, does anyone know why Java does not offer this ability while so many other languages (C++ for example) do? Is it some kind of law violation in the space of rigid OOP standards?

No strongly held beliefs, no. It's more complicated than you might think and the team is working on other stuff; it won't be there in one of the next 2 to 3 versions, but maybe later (note that one version comes out every 6 months).

> So my question is, can this be done by ANY means at all - third-party options maybe?

Builder pattern or lombok-style annotation processor seem relevant. We (from Project Lombok) haven't added it yet because, well, its really complicated. What if your default is `System.currentTimeMillis()`, that should probably be calculated 'live', every time you invoke the method. But what if the default is 'someComplexConstant', should that be pointlessly re-calculated every time? I'm sure you have a preference but that's the exact problem: Some want A, some want B, and neither camp has a 90%+ market share, which means you have a gigantic chunk of programmers who get a nasty surprise (example: Python's default args are evalled only once. 're-eval every time' is on its face more sensible but folks always bring baggage from other languages they know, and thus trivially you get to "neither camp has an overwhelming majority", which is, at least for us, a showstopper).

Possibly the solution is to simply not allow anything that isn't compile-time-constant, but then you bother users with the definition of CTCs which aren't as clear cut as one might think (did you know `null` isn't one, for example? Maybe we should allow all CTCs and also `null`... but something like `LocalDate.of(1900, 1, 1)` also isn't one and that seems like quite a big annoyance!).

The cost of building this on your own is highly unlikely to be worth your while. If you really want, you could make a 'template' class that is never used by anything, except an annotation processor, which then makes the actual source file you really want. However, going down this road has significant dev process downsides: Your code is just broken until you run a full compile build with annotation processors on, which takes time, and therefore slows your dev cycle way down. Anytime you mess with the 'template' you are likely going to end up with 'everything is totally broken until we do a full clean and rebuild cycle', and if you're doing that, you're doing it wrong. You want to see the effects of anything you write to be visible in at most 2 seconds - hot code replace, incremental compilation, and fast boots are crucial (and you get HCR in eclipse for free, and IC in just about every IDE).

Lombok gets around this by directly patching your IDE to handle the annotations as-you-type and incrementally, but as I mentioned, this is a major feature that is tricky to implement, and right now lombok sticks to the rule that simple annotation processing must be able to do the job, and that means the input source file must be syntactically correct. `void foo(int x = 5)` isn't, and the alternatives suck (`void foo(@DefaultValueInt(5) x)`? Meh).

A third option is to just forego that idea of syntactically valid java and patch everything. But at some point you have to admit you're just writing software that will take over all systems on boot and hacks/patches all relevant tools to actually parse/support a language that isn't java anymore.

We could try to support `LocalDate.of` and hardcode a big list of 'known' constant values, or allow hackery where you set as default value a static final field, which you can then define however you like. This will all work, but the point of a nice feature is presumably that it makes sense to all. If you need to read 5 pages of documentation and re-read it after a month because the actual way it works just doesn't feel logical to you - that's a real problem.

Also, the effort needed to write lombok or something like it, let alone maintain it, is quite significant.

SOURCE: I've been a core lombok dev for about 12 years now :)

Comment: Holy cow! THAT is an answer I could never have anticipated. Though I understand now what you guys are facing in this particular use case of the language. I'm sure you have all discussed other options whereby some of these complications can be mitigated or eliminated by more narrowly defining the way in which this could be implemented - like say only allow default values to be assigned when those values are existing instantiated classes like String, int etc. where it is not necessary to calculate or derive the value being assigned - maybe as a starting point?

Comment: I think what I'm getting at here, is if the reason why this ability does not exist in Java is that advanced implementations of the feature are a point of contention among high-end developers, then why not say, "we will deal with those use cases in time, but for now, lets at least offer a basic implementation where doing so does not require complex engineering" - such as my example where the value I need to pass is a String requiring no complex code to get to the value. Certainly, even a basic implementation as a starting point would help countless developers reduce their code footprint.

Comment: I would also add that offering such an implementation would inspire many developers to step out of the 1.8 "safety zone" (as I like to call it) where so many developers see no need to use newer versions of Java. The changes made in switch case were excellent and when such conveniences are continually added to java, developers will see value in using newer versions. But that's just my opinion - speaking from my own experience at least.

Comment: Yes, 'only string and int literals, and null' is a worthwhile simplification. We then get into the problems of syntax (obviously `void foo(int x = 5)` is nicest, but that just isn't a possibility. There's also the combinatorial explosion, but that's easily solved by only going in linear order (`void foo(int a = 1, long b = 2, short b = 3)` gives you `foo()`, `foo(int a)`, `foo(int a, long b)`, `foo(int a, long b, short c)`. Not `foo(long b)`, for example. But sometimes that is what you wanted... also tricky.

Comment: Why not just start and figure out the complex cases later: Because java wants to remain backwards compatible and sometimes starting off in one direction closes doors. You need to at least do some due diligence on how one might tackle the more advanced use cases before starting off. 'preview features' are useful here - they offer the opportunity for the openjdk team to introduce features and break them later. Lombok has this too (the `lombok.experimental` package).

Comment: _About the 1.8 safety zone_  -- nope. java17 has _plenty_ of convincing features. The problem is, java 9 broke a lot and java17 broke a lot more, and those stuck on 1.8 are stuck there because of OpenJDK team breaking way too much. The fix is to have patience, be nicer to library developers, and break less. Not to add an 8th golden apple to the pile of 7 that are already there.

Comment: Well ... it was an idea that sounded simple enough ... clearly, the world of Java language development is far more complex than most people probably realize or appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a structure like this:

```
interface ContextFactory {
  Context getDefaultContext();
  Context getExplicitContext(String objectName);
}

interface Context {
  void getThis(float value);
}
```

Incidentally you are not doing users of your library any favours by giving them static methods. How will they unit test their code?

Suppose I write:

```
...
void doIt() {
  if (Library.getThis(10) > 0) {
    service.effectSomething();
  } else {
    service.effectSomethingElse();
  }
}
...
```

and I want to write a unit test for that function.

I somehow have to set things up so that in one of my test cases `Library.getThis(10)` returns greater than zero, and in another test case it returns zero or less.

If I have an interface I can mock which has been injected into my class, then it's easy. If I'm calling static methods then it's hard.

Comment: The Library is primarily a utility class that is relevant in its context. It would defeat its purpose to require it to be instantiated because it is intended to be used globally in a project. Though I realize that a developer could declare it globally in their project, my goal is to keep it simple. But I am open to other ideas or discussion on the topic as I am always eager to learn how to do things the right way.

Comment: Lookig at your example of using interface - I've never used an Interface before, so I read some tutorials on their use and it still isn't clear to me how I can offer the user of the library the ability to pass in their own String for objectName while also providing the ability to not pass in that String whereby the library uses the default value. In other words, I can't see how this allows me to write one method that will handle both scenarios. Could you modify your answer to include an example of how this would work?